# Pushing values in Ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to build a status comment type of system using angularJS. The first textbox allows the user to put the value in an array and thus display it on the page. On clicking also allows a textbox and a button to enter the comment. The value of comment however is not displaying inside the scope. The code is :

**HTML**

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="status.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

<div>
<h2>Status!</h2>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Post status here :<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="value"></textarea>
<button ng-click="addstatus()">Click to Add!</button>
<br><br><br>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="add in statushow">
                    <td><h3>{{add.value}}</h3>
                     <input ng-model="commentvalue" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Enter your comment here!"></input>
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <button ng-click="addcomment()">Add comment!</button>
                        <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="comms in comments">
                        <td><h4>{{comms.commentvalue}}</h4></td></tr></table>

                    </td>


        </tr>
    </table>
    {{commentvalue}}
    </div>
```

**STATUS.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.statushow = [];
    $scope.comments = [];

    $scope.addcomment= function(){
        $scope.comments.push({
            commentvalue: $scope.commentvalue
        });
        $scope.value="";
    };

    $scope.addstatus= function(){
        $scope.statushow.push({
            value: $scope.value
        });
        $scope.value="";
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this http://jsfiddle.net/rrfqaf9L/2/:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

<h2>Status!</h2>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Post status here :
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="value"></textarea>
<button ng-click="addstatus()">Click to Add!</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="add in statushow">
        <td>
            <h3>{{add.value}}</h3>

            <input ng-model="add.commentvalue" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Enter your comment here!"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button ng-click="addcomment(add)">Add comment!</button>
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="comms in add.comments">
                    <td>
                        <h4>{{comms.commentvalue}}</h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>{{commentvalue}}</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.statushow = [];

$scope.addcomment= function(add){
    if (typeof add.comments == 'undefined') add.comments = [];
    add.comments.push({
        commentvalue: add.commentvalue
    });
    add.commentvalue="";
};

$scope.addstatus= function(){
    $scope.statushow.push({
        value: $scope.value
    });
    $scope.value="";
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be not to use specific keywords such as add, value as model or variable names.

You could send the model through the function as a parameter:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="status"></textarea>
<button ng-click="addstatus(status)">Click to Add!</button>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="stat in statushow">
            <td><h3>{{stat.value}}</h3>
               <input ng-model="commentvalue" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Enter your comment here!"></input>
                <button ng-click="addcomment(commentvalue)">Add comment!</button>
         <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="comms in comments">
                <td><h4>{{comms.commentvalue}}</h4></td></tr></table>

           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{commentvalue}}
    </div>
```

Modify the controller as:

```
$scope.addcomment= function(comment){
        $scope.comments.push({
            commentvalue: comment
        });
    };

    $scope.addstatus= function(status){
        $scope.statushow.push({
            statusvalue: status
        });
    };
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15033/

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do it would be to change the following and add `$parent`. NG-Repeat creates child scopes, so the input box wasn't adding the correct scope.

```
<input ng-model="$parent.commentvalue" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Enter your comment here!"></input>
```

Here's the code pen.
http://codepen.io/shuffguy/pen/gpezOM?editors=101